# Binding of Variables at Compile Time and Runtime

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

I am trying to execute the following code to clear the concept of  method binding at Runtime.I have three classes  **Employee.java**, **Programmer.java**,and **JPolymorphism.java**. I am trying to print the methods from employee and Programmer class.In method compilation is at runtime. By this way Programmer should be printed by the **programmer.name** but its printing Employee

Employee.java

```
package jpolymorphism;
class Employee {
    String name = "Employee";

    void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Programmer.java

```
package jpolymorphism;
class Programmer extends Employee {
    String name = "Programmer";

    void print() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Test Clas

```
package jpolymorphism;
class JPolymorphism {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        System.out.println(emp.name);
        Employee programmer = new Programmer();
        System.out.println(programmer.name);
        emp.printName();
        //The below code line shoul print Prograamer at run time 
        //but my code is prininting Employee Instead of Programmer
        programmer.printName();
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand ***Where is the error?*** As methods are binding at runtime and my last line of code **programmer.name** is of  Programmer type and referance type is of employee type then according to the concept the line should pring Prograamer but it is also printing Employee .Where am i doing the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
System.out.println(emp.name);
```

That prints `Employee`, obviously.

```
Employee programmer = new Programmer();
System.out.println(programmer.name);
```

That prints `Employee`, because field binding happens at compile-time, so `programmer.name` refers to the `Employee.name` field, since `programmer` is declared as `Employee`.

```
emp.printName();
```

That prints `Employee`, obviously.

```
programmer.printName();
```

That prints `Employee`, because you're calling the `Employee.printName()` method, which accesses the `Employee.name` field, and the method has not been overridden by subclass `Programmer`.

Why wasn't it overridden? Because the **`Programmer` method is named `print`, not `printName`**. If you had added the `@Override` annotation, as you should if you intended the method to override a superclass method, then the compiler would have told you that you had a problem.

If you rename the `Programmer` method to `printName`:

- A good IDE would tell you to add the `@Override` annotation.
- The `programmer.printName()` call will print `Programmer`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that when you are calling `programmer.printName();`, it is calling the `printName()` function of the `Employee` class for which the variable is `name` whose value is "Employee".

The thing is that even though `Programmer` is a subclass of `Employee`, the variable `name` of the `Programmer` class is not accessible to `Employee` class. In inheritance, properties are inherited from the superclass, in this case, `Employee` but `Employee` cannot access the fields of its subclasses directly. So, when the `programmer.printName();` invocation is done, the `printName()` method of the `Employee` class gets called and the value "Employee" gets printed.

As such the code does not reflect the concept of method binding at runtime as there is no override of a function as pointed out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908360/9457268).